# Embedding SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 Report Manager causing AJAX requests with no POST variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ajax, reporting-services

I'm working on a web project which uses AJAX requests to dynamically generate HTML.

I'm currently trying to integrate SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 into this project by embedding 
the Report Manager into a generated iFrame. I'm able to embed the Report Manager successfully and use it without a problem.

The issue at hand is that once the Report Manager is loaded, other AJAX requests made by the system are periodically affected.

Under normal circumstances, these requests would always pass along POST variables to the server. Once the Report Manager is loaded, the differences I can spot for erroneous requests are:

- the requests made have no POST variables
- the requests made have an extra header field with the key-value **Authorization: Negotiate 
  (long encrypted string)** which I'm presuming is generated by Reporting Services

Can anyone point me to how to resolve this so Reporting Services doesn't alter AJAX requests generated by the system?

Comment: Hi Felix I do recall a similar problem where I used the AJAX session manager, it was a couple of years ago and I can't remember the details, but it was in the AJAX toolkit